# Confused when implementing a print function for a deque class that is only using the STL list

Tags: c++

This is an assignment that has you implement a deque with just a list STL. I am 95% done with this specific assignment, and only need this function fixed. There are two parameters, one being an output with `ostream` and the other being a deque object reference. Since we are trying to output the list we created with the STL that I provided with the constructor.

Constructor:

```
template <typename T>
  deque<T>::deque(){
    std::list<T> l;
  }
```

Here is where I am having trouble, I tried to create a const iterator and looping with `dq.front()` to `dq.back()` which were functions that returned `l.front()` and `l.back()` respectively. I used something similar in a previous assignment that just used the list STL exclusively to showcase the list but now with the deque object, it is confusing me terribly. I know the reason for the errors is because you can't use a list iterator and use with the `=` operator with a function from the object `dq`.

```
template <typename U>
  std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const deque<U>& dq){
    typename std::list<U>::const_iterator i;
    //typename std::deque<U>::const_iterator i;
    for (i = dq.front(); i != dq.back(); ++i){
        out << *i << " ";
    }

    return out;
  }
```

My error messages are currently:

```
deque.template:105:9: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::__cxx11::list<int, std::allocator<int> >::const_iterator {aka std::_List_const_iterator<int>}’ and ‘int’)
  for (i = dq.front(); i != dq.back(); ++i){
deque.template:105:25: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ (operand types are ‘std::__cxx11::list<int, std::allocator<int> >::const_iterator {aka std::_List_const_iterator<int>}’ and ‘int’)
  for (i = dq.front(); i != dq.back(); ++i){
                         ^
```

Comment: A deque isn't (simply) a linked-list - they have completely different performance characteristics.

Comment: Is `deque` a custom class or [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)?

Comment: @KillzoneKid yes, it is a custom class

Comment: *I know the reason for the errors is because you can't use a list iterator and use with the "=" operator with a function from the object "dq".* -- What is the return value type of `dq.front()` and `dq.back()`?  When I see `front()` and `back()`, to me they denote references to the values at the first and last items, not iterators to those items.

Comment: @BasitonSmith Very confusing. So if the `.front()` and the `.back()` are methods of `std::list` and you need an iterator, perhaps you need `.beg()` and `.end()`. Difficult to say from what you posted.

Comment: Yes I think you've just got confused between front/back and begin/end.

Comment: Don't keep us guessing. Post a [MCVE].  Also, use `auto` whenever you can. Try `for(auto i = dq.begin(); i != dq.end(); ++i) `...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jonathan Wakely points out, you've got `front` & `back` confused with `begin` and `end`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343221/confused-when-implementing-a-print-function-for-a-deque-class-that-is-only-using#comment85687097_49343221)

[`front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/front) and [`back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/back) respectively: "Return a reference to the first/last element in the container"
[`begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) respectively: "Returns an iterator to the beginning/end of the given container"

---

But aside from swapping `front`/`back` for `begin`/`end`, you can use more standard functionality to separate your function from type dependence. So hopefully in the very near future when you start using a `deque` as a `deque` instead of a `list` as a `deque` this function will still work:

```
template <typename U>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const deque<U>& dq) {
    std::copy(std::cbegin(dq), std::cend(dq), std::ostream_iterator<int>(out, " "));

    return out;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/g9pQRk)